# Using alert with object date

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm trying to figure out object date. Specifically toLocaleDateString method.
I've come across two different basic examples of it. The first one is:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
alert(d);
```

And the second one is:

```
var myDate = new Date();
alert(myDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

Both work fine, but they give different date formats. First one gives: `Mon Jul 16 2018 18:34:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`, while the second one is just `7/16/2018`. And I can't see why? What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: `alert(d);` try `alert(n);` it's probably a typo you made, but `n` is locale date string and `d` is the original date

Comment: In the first block of code you're printing the Date without formatting, change alert(d) to alert(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small error, in the first example you should be alerting n instead of d

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
alert(n);
```

d is the date object while n is the date string. you are getting different date formats because you are alerting a date object in the first example and a date string in the second

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation too! It makes sense now!!

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because you are not alerting the modified date string (which is `n`) in the first alert:

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
alert(n);

var myDate = new Date();
alert(myDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the wrong variable in the first block. When you declare a variable with the reserved word var in the second line you're storing there the formatted date that you want to output, so you can just alert(n) or you can avoid declaring the var:

```
var d = new Date();
d.toLocaleDateString();
alert(d);
```